# Cultural Buildings and Hired Armies

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Are my hired armies (Retinues/Merc/Holy Order) at all affected by my cultural buildings in any holding? They aren't trained in my realm, except for vassalized holy orders, so I assume no.

Answer (score 3):

Looking it up, hired Retinues use the cultural building in your capital. I could not find if this is true for mercenaries, and I doubt it is true for holy orders as they frequently have their own holdings.

Source: http://www.ckiiwiki.com/Retinues#Cultural_retinues

Comment: can you provide a reference or more body to back up your answer?